# Can I detect that the app in not running state is started by background mode?

Tags: ios, swift

In Swift 4, I am creating apps related to Beacon and BLE.

Can you distinguish between when a user runs an app and when a system executes an app?
I tried to use `willAppear` or `didAppear` because the app's screen appears only when the user is running, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: You can use AppDelegate class application callbacks methods for different states of the application.

Comment: [`UIApplication.shared.applicationState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623003-applicationstate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AppDelegate, [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate) is the documentationation link. Take a look on

```
func application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool
```

There you have UIApplicatio.LaunchOptionsKey you can check them [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/launchoptionskey).

Also, two useful things that you can use are

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(UIApplication)
willEnterForegroundNotification
```

The second one is a notification for which you can add observer and do something once when you received.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. If I were to use "WillEnterForegroundNotification," would that function be performed when users put the app back on top?

Answer (score 0):

Under AppDelegate :

- applicationDidEnterBackground : This method is called to let app know that it is not running in the foreground.
- applicationWillEnterForeground : This method is called as a part of the transition from the background to the active state. You should use this to undo any change you made to your app upon entering the background.
- applicationDidBecomeActive: method is called soon after this method has finished its execution which then moves the app from the inactive to the active state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
If you run the app yourself, doesn't "applicationDidEnterBackground" come in?

Comment: No, it doesn't.